# Wordpress Plugin Insert Html Code with Shortcode

Tags: plugins, shortcode, html

I want to insert an HTML block with a Contact form 7 shortcode. How I can insert the HTML before the shortcode is being converted to HTML?

```
function custom_shortcode_func() {
    $html = <<<HTML
        <h1>[contact-form-7 id="10" title="Contact form 1"]</h1>
    HTML;

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('test_form','custom_shortcode_func');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `do_shortcode` to process any shortcodes inside a string

Comment: Oh, thanks, man!